# How to debug a "Default namespace of the document is incorrect" XML parsing error?

Tags: xml, excel, xsd

I'm trying to troubleshoot a failed xml export. The issue has to do with an incorrect namespace but I"m not certain how to resolve:

> Error Log:
>
> `<TDBUIDataProcessingResults xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.att.com/pace/r2.4/v1"><FileCreationDate>2016-05-10T22:19:01-8:00</FileCreationDate><TDBUIDataProcessingResultsList><PaceJobNumber />**<TaskData><ProcessStatus>`
>
> PACE_TV_TDU_101-Incorrect file format: Incorrect file format: Default namespace of the document is incorrect.
>
> Expected:
>   http://www.att.com/pace/r2.4/v1,
>
> Received: `</ProcessStatus><ErrorDateTime>2016-05-10T22:19:01-8:00**</ErrorDateTime></TaskData></TDBUIDataProcessingResultsList></TDBUIDataProces`

Here is the XML MAP. The xml was created in Excel using an excel file created by someone else (so mapping was already in place). I was able to get to the original map file by turning my excel file into a zip and opening up xmlmap file. I know the issue is essentially pasting in the namespace, but i'm not entirely sure where. Below is the xml map:

```
<MapInfo xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main"
         SelectionNamespaces=""> <!-- I THINK THIS IS THE PROBLEM ATTRIBUTE -->
  <Schema ID="Schema1">
    <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
               elementFormDefault="qualified" 
               attributeFormDefault="unqualified" 
               xmlns="">
      <!-- XML Schema Generated from XML Document on Thu Jan 29 2015 15:48:01 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time) -->
      <!-- with XmlGrid.net Free Online Service http://xmlgrid.net -->            
      <xs:element name="TDBUIData">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="FileCreationDate" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
            <xs:element name="TDBUIDataList" maxOccurs="unbounded">
              <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element name="PaceJobNumber" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                  <xs:element name="TaskData">
                    <xs:complexType>
                      <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="TaskCode" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                        <xs:element name="TaskAssigneeForecastFinishDate" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                        <xs:element name="ActualFinishDate" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                      </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                  </xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
              </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
          </xs:sequence>
          <xs:attribute name="xml" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
        </xs:complexType>           
      </xs:element>       
    </xs:schema>    
  </Schema>
  <Schema ID="Schema2">
    <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
                xmlns=""><!-- POSSIBLE PROBLEM ATTRIBUTE? -->
      <xsd:element nillable="true" name="TDBUIData">
        <xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:sequence minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:element minOccurs="0" 
                         nillable="true" 
                         type="xsd:string" 
                         name="FileCreationDate" 
                         form="unqualified">
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element minOccurs="0"
                         nillable="true"
                         name="TDBUIDataList" 
                         form="unqualified">
              <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence minOccurs="0">
                  <xsd:element minOccurs="0" 
                               nillable="true"
                               type="xsd:string"
                               name="PaceJobNumber"
                               form="unqualified">
                  </xsd:element>
                  <xsd:element minOccurs="0" 
                               nillable="true"
                               name="TaskData"
                               form="unqualified">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                      <xsd:sequence minOccurs="0">
                        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" 
                                     nillable="true"
                                     type="xsd:string"
                                     name="TaskCode"
                                     form="unqualified">
                        </xsd:element>
                        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" 
                                     nillable="true"
                                     type="xsd:string"
                                     name="ActualFinishDate"
                                     form="unqualified">
                        </xsd:element>
                      </xsd:sequence>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                  </xsd:element>
                </xsd:sequence>
              </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
          </xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:attribute name="xml" form="unqualified" type="xsd:dateTime">
          </xsd:attribute>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
  </xsd:schema>  </Schema>
  <Map ID="1" 
       Name="TDBUIData_Map"
       RootElement="TDBUIData"
       SchemaID="Schema1"
       ShowImportExportValidationErrors="false"
       AutoFit="true"
       Append="false"
       PreserveSortAFLayout="true"
       PreserveFormat="true"/>
  <Map ID="2"
       Name="TDBUIData_Map1"
       RootElement="TDBUIData"
       SchemaID="Schema2"
       ShowImportExportValidationErrors="false"
       AutoFit="true"
       Append="false"
       PreserveSortAFLayout="true"
       PreserveFormat="true">
    <DataBinding FileBinding="true" 
                 ConnectionID="2"
                 DataBindingLoadMode="1"/>
  </Map>
</MapInfo>
```

I've highlighted where I believe the ns should be [later changed to comments, since highlighting doesn't work inside code blocks], but I was hoping someone could verify and explain.

Comment: markdown doesn't work inside code blocks - I've edited your question to add a code comment where you think the issue was.

Comment: Please provide more information on the XML you are currently parsing in input. From what I can see from the log is that your input XML document has the default namespace `xmlns="http://www.att.com/pace/r2.4/v1"` but according to the schema (XSD) this element is not declared to be in the this target namespace. Try adding `targetNamespace="http://www.att.com/pace/r2.4/v1"` on the `<xs:schema>` element.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I'll try that. I noticed this on my xml output:
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<TDBUIData xml="">
 <FileCreationDate>2016-05-10T10:00</FileCreationDate>

Am I naive in thinking simply pasting the desired ns in the quotes in line 2 will resolve the error? Ultimately I do need to declare the ns properly in the map so the xml can produce automatically, but I"m hoping replacing the "" with "http://www.att.com/pace/r2.4/v1" allows the initial upload to go through. Thoughts?

Comment: Hard to answer without more information.  What program is issuing this error message, what requirements does it impose on namespace usage, and what document is it complaining about?  If it's complaining about the `MapInfo` document you show, and it's complaining about the default namespace in "the document", then setting the default namespace in the document to the one apparently expected by the processor is probably a good first step.

Comment: THANKS! So i went into the xml file that i was exporting and changed <TDBUIDATA xml=""> to <TDBUIDATA xmlns="att.com/pace/r2.4/v1"> and the file took! Thanks for your help and patience on this matter. I'll go into the mapping and declare the ns as you prescribed above as well.

Comment: How do you thumbs up a User, or essentially thank them in a public manner on this board? is there a button I dont see?